# Не получается сохранить результат работы программы в файл

Tags: ubuntu

Программа распознования речи `pocketsphinx_continuous -samprate 16000  -nfft 2048  -hmm zero_ru.cd_cont_4000 -dict vacabular.dict  -jsgf calc.jsqf  -inmic yes -logfn /dev/null` запускается с такими параметрами. Удачно распознает, и выводит в консоль:

```
  Listening...
 дом аквариум включить свет
  READY....
```

При перенаправлении в другой файл файл остается пустой. Возможно ли получить фрагмент текста распознованого в файл или что будет лучше запустить другую программу с параметром этого текста?
При использовании параметра `-hyp file.txt` говорит что параметр не верный.
Система Ubuntu 16.04, pocketsphinx_continuous из репозитория

Comment: 1. у процесса есть право записи в этот файл? 2. на всякий случай запустите: `$ команда &> /tmp/несуществующий-файл` и смотрите в этом файле.

Comment: в заголовке следует вашу проблему указывать (к примеру: «пустой вывод при перенаправлении в файл, непустой вывод  при выводе в терминал у pocketsphinx_continuous утилиты»). Эта проблема может часто происходить и с другими утилитами, которые генерируют вывод, продолжая работать.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/1321)

Comment: Если запусть без параметра `-logfn /dev/null` и перенаправить вывод в файл там появляется отладочная информация. Если уже запустить с параметром тогда уже вывод который выше. Его и надо поймать